# Blinking minimized browser

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, browser, minimized

when my single IE instance is opened then minimized browser is blinking but while setting task bar property "Group similar task bar button" and if multiple IE instances opened then blinking is not working.

i have written follwoing code for this..

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>");
Response.Write("var oldTitle = document.title;");
Response.Write("function stay(){ ");
Response.Write("document.title = 'CTMS | Exception Dashboard - Microsoft Internet Explorer'; } ");                        
Response.Write(" function go() { ");
Response.Write(" document.title = 'New Message Arrived!';");                        
Response.Write(" for(var i=900; i < 10500; i=i+900) {");
Response.Write(" setTimeout('stay()',i+450);");
Response.Write(" setTimeout('go()',i); } ");
Response.Write("</script> ");
```

Comment: Why are you writing the script using `Response.Write`?

Comment: I suspect this might just be the way Windows works.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has nothing to do with that. The blinking in the tray is a default Windows behavior.

When you have a grouped set of IE windows it doesn't blink the group in the taskbar because it wouldn't be able to blink for just the single window that needs focus, it would have to blink the entire group. And if it blinked the entire group that wouldn't tell you which window wants attention, so Microsoft chose to just turn the blinking off.